# htaccess disable Wordpress rewrite rules for folder and its contents

Tags: htaccess

I have another PHP application in a folder named `app` inside my Wordpress installation, and I need to disable all Wordpress rewrite rules for that folder and it's content. So that when I go to `www.domain.com/app` I get my application page, instead of the standard Wordpress 404 page.

I know this is pretty basic apache rewrite rules, and i searched for this, tried some things and didn't work well.

Almost forgot, i need to do this only by editing Wordpress htaccess file. And the app has it's own htaccess file.

Thanks.

**EDIT: htaccess content**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT: Application htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<FilesMatch "\.(php|inc)$">
Order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(index.php|download.php)$">
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

These rules don't do much, they basically deny access to all `PHP` and `INC` file types, except `index.php` and `download.php`. Which are the ones the user needs to access, the rest of them are classes used internally by `PHP`.

**EDIT 3: Resolution:**

As it turns out, there was nothing wrong with the Wordpress `htaccess` or the application, after turning error reporting on remote hosting server, PHP reported a corrupted file, once replaced, all started to work well. My thanks to [Wietse Venema](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3637/wietse-venema) for the suggestion.

Comment: @Fábio: Can you also give us the `.htaccess` rules from the app? Is it a public app, or developed on top of a public framework (something we can know)?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Sure just a second. The application doesn't use any Framework, was built from scratch, just for kicks and to keep good habits.

Comment: if you go to `www.domain.com/app/index.php`, do you also get the Wordpress 404?

Comment: @Wietse Venema: Any other location inside 'app' reports Wordpress 404, in case of the index.php, I just get a blank response. Like there was nothing inside the file to be processed.

Comment: Just to be sure; if you add a static file test.html with some text to the app/ directory, do you get a Wordpress 404 also?

Comment: No error. I get the file. Funny, it seems that inside my app folder PHP ain't being executed.

Comment: It might be that is actually is being executed, but it throws an error that you don't see. Try reading your errorlog or put `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` just after the opening `<?` of your index.php.

Comment: @Wietse Venema: I was so comfortable developing and watching it work on my local machine, that I never tough something could be wrong. Once I turned error reporting on the host server reported a corrupted file (probably during ftp upload), once replaced it started to work as it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default .htaccess-file will already support the behaviour you want;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The magic is in the lines that start with *[RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)*. They instruct Apache to apply the rule `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` (which means "any URL will go to index.php"), only when the URL is not an existing file `!-f` or existing directory `!-d`.

So this should work by default. The Wordpress rewrite rules do not apply when you try to visit an already existing file.

Comment: Of course, if the app also uses rewrites to map non-existing URLs to itself, this will not work. Then you need a specific condition that the URL should not start with `app/`.